# Axios get request via NextJs is taking too long when under load

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, axios, next.js

I have a page that makes API call to a Django based backend in getInitialProps(). This call is taking 50-70s on average. I'm using Axios request/response interceptors to log the request duration. Initially we were assuming it was backend that is slow, but it seems to return a response in fraction of a second while at the same time NextJS application which is under 7req/s load is taking more than a minute. Also we see a significant increase in memory during this load.

Any hints as to how we can debug this?
We're using Node 10 and Next 10.

Comment: Why are you using the Node 10 version? Any specific reason? So, you have Client -> Next.js App -> Django Backend? Where it is taking longer to process? The time is for 1 request? And It is the only request processed or there are multiple requests?

Comment: Having other challenges to upgrade node, but I believe it shouldn't be an issue. So if I'm hitting an NextJs Page multiple times, which is calling Django API once in getInitialProps, the response time of this Django API is slowly increasing from milliseconds to 70 seconds.. while at the same time if I'm hitting Django API, it's taking less than a second. So there's no issue with Django endpoint.